# How many flowers can a single muscari plant grow?

Tags: bulbs, grape-hyacinth

My muscari(s) are flowering, with one stalk each, but I found a new bud coming out from the base of each muscari. I think it is another flower stalk.

Can a muscari plant have more than 1 flowering stalk at a time? If so, how many can they grow?
I froze them in fridge for 3 months before planting.

Answer (score 2):

Muscaris can reproduce vegetatively (asexual reproduction), similar to how mints reproduce by stolons, onions by forming new bulbs, growth from cuttings, etc. In your case, the plant has produced a new bulb underground, which has given rise to a new flowering stalk. There are a couple of excellent pictures on Wikipedia showing this:

[image]
[image]

<sub>Source: Wikimedia Commons

 1. [Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Muscari_displaying_vegetative_reproduction.JPG) – [Gut Monk](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Gut_Monk)

 2. [Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Blauwe_druif_vdg.jpg) – [Vincent de Groot](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Vdegroot)</sub>